# Percona XtraDB Cluster With Async slaves

Tags: mysql, percona, xtradb-cluster

I have set up a 3 node percona cluster in amazon ec2. As our client required, i also had to set up an asynchronous slaves in another datacenter as well. Each async slave pointed to single percona cluster node with log-slave-updates and bin-log enabled.

However the async slaves failed to maintain the replication process for long. At least once a week i have to build the slaves from scratch. These async slaves are used only for backup purpose.

Is there any alternative method(best way) of doing this?

Percona Cluster ---> async slaves ?

Comment: That's the correct way to do it.  It might be helpful if you mentioned the the specific versions of the servers, and in what way the slaves "failed to maintain the replication process" -- there's more than one way to break replication, after all... and whether different slaves pointed to different nodes as masters failed at the same time, or not...

Comment: What is `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'binlog_format';` on the Slaves ?

Comment: Binlog_format is "ROW"

Comment: What does "failed to maintain the replication process" mean? When you run `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` on the slaves, what error, if any, is listed?